# Как отобразить правую часть картинки в css

Tags: html, css

Посмотрел этот [гайд](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-cropping-images-object-fit)
И у меня не получается сделать так чтобы изображение показывалось с правой части (необходимо большое изображение показать только правую его часть)

Как такое сделать?
https://codepen.io/Nicitaa/pen/zYjbVyr

**html**

```
  <body>
    
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Title1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, fuga repellendus ad distinctio.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


</body>
```

**css**

```
.header {
  background-color: #303030;
  background-image: url(https://images3.alphacoders.com/127/127957.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  -o-object-position: -20% 0;
     object-position: -20% 0;
}
.container {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background-position: right;
```

Также можно в процентах указать

```
background-position: 60% 30%;
```

Первое значение `60%` это отступ справа на 60%
Второе значение `30%` это отступ сверху на 30%

**css**

```
body {
    background-color: #202020;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    color:white;
}

.header {
  background-color: #303030;
  background-image: url(https://images3.alphacoders.com/127/127957.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
/*  -o-object-position: -20% 0;
     object-position: -20% 0;*/
     background-position: 60%;
}
.container {
  height: 400px;
}
```